# Recently installed Ubuntu, Wifi is not working. How do I fix this?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Just installed my first Linux Distro; Ubuntu 14.04 and I couldn't access the wifi. I tried following some other guides but all of them didn't and gave me Errors.
Can I have some clear instructions as to what I should do? (considering I have no idea how to code let alone use Ubuntu efficiently)
I'm not allowed to post screenshots/images but I don't have any wifi options in the drop down menu on the top right of the bar.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` gives:

```
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN [103c:1356]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Do you have a wired internet access in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, that's how im on the internet currently. Using an ethernet cable

Comment: I made an easy solution for you. Look down.

Comment: Ok it seemed to work for the most part. But just to be sure what is meant by "After you follow this guide, you will NEED to test your wireless connection for at least 2 hours (I actually recommend 8 hours) with another device in either Ad-Hoc Mode, Infrastructure Mode or Both" ? And how will i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

and Wi-Fi will work.

Comment: Well I take that back... It seems while the Wifi has been enabled and i can seen all the networks i am not able to connect to them :/ I've gone back to the wired connection for now

Comment: @NickHarper Turn off your wired connection, then wireless will work.